# Showing $|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq (n+1)!e.$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f(z)\in H(D)$ and suppose that 
$$|f(z)|\leq\frac{1}{1-|z|}\:\:\: \text{for all }\:\:z\in D.$$

Show that

$$|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq (n+1)!e.$$

Applying Cauchy integral formula I get the following inequality, however I don't know how to obtain $(n+1)!e$ as an upper bound. Thank you!

$$|f^{(n)}(0)|=\frac{n!}{2\pi 
}|\int_{D}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz|$$
$$\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi 
}\int_{D}|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}|.|dz|$$
$$\leq\frac{n!}{2\pi 
}\int_{D}\frac{1}{|z^{n+1}|(1-|z|)}.|dz|. $$

Comment: What is D in your case? If it is a circle, then you should be able to calculate the curve integral

Comment: There are some minor problems with your calculation. First of all, you should be more careful when taking absolute values, as you missed that $|\frac{n!}{2 \pi i}| = \frac{n!}{2 \pi}$. Also, $|dz|$ makes no sense. Moreover, the Cauchy integral formula does not tell you to integrate over $D$, the whole domain of $f$, but over some circle around $0$.

Comment: @TheOscillator that's the problem, I believe it's a disc of radius 1 and center $0$.

Comment: Well, if $D$ is the unit disc and $C_n$ is the counter-clockwise oriented circular contour of radius $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ centered at $0$, $$ |f^{(n)}(0)| = \left| \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{C_n} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \, dz \right| \leq \frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_{C_n} \frac{ds}{|z|^{n+1}(1 - |z|)}. $$ Since the integrand is constant over the circle, you can simply this bound and then utilize the inequality $\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{-n} \leq e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see with Cauchy integral formula, for $r<1$
$$f^{(n)}(0)=\dfrac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$
and $z=re^{i\theta}$
$$|f^{(n)}(0)| \leqslant \dfrac{n!}{2\pi r^n}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta \leqslant \dfrac{n!}{2\pi r^n}\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{1-r}d\theta = \dfrac{n!}{r^n(1-r)}$$
The function $g(r)=\dfrac{1}{r^n(1-r)}$ is maximum in $r=\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ so with substitution you find
$$|f^{(n)}(0)| \leqslant n!(n+1)\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n\leqslant(n+1)!e$$

Comment: Thanks eynakeman

Comment: Your welcome !.